# How to disable scroll of iframe in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I'm developing Hybrid E-commerce app using `Ionic Framework v3`. I have set iframe in my app with third party url. Its working properly but **i want to disable scrolling inside iframe**. I have tried many things like

1. `scrolling="no"` set inside iframe
2. `iframe { overflow: hidden }` Set css
3. `$("iframe").contents().find("#body").addClass("iframeclass")` I have also use jQuery but no luck.

I can disable it manually from browser when i set `overflow: hidden` inside iframe > html > Body tag, but don't know how to do it with code.

Here is my code please check and suggest me proper way.

```
 <iframe class="iframPlace" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(browselink)" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if set width and height for iframe, bigger than source, scroll is hidden otherwise iframe have a scroll because an HTML iframe is used to display a full web page within in web page and it's impossible to disable scroll.